# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' react native

Tags: android, react-native

I am trying to run react native app on my android device like this in cmd

```
cd C:\Users\User\Desktop\js

react-native run-android
```

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Could not find tools.jar
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 5.243 secs Could not install the app on the device, read
>   the error above for details. Make sure you have an Android emulator
>   running or a device connected and have set up your Android development
>   environment:
>   https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/android-setup.html

Can anyone please tell me how to fix this problem?

Comment: have you cleaned your gradle and tried to run it again?

Comment: @stutikasliwal but I haven't create an android app,do I need to do that?

Comment: you are running android command that means you wrote for android, right?

Comment: That's react native folder with index.android,node_modules and etc.

Comment: yeah `cd android & ./gradlew clean` try to run this from your cmd

Comment: I will try i now.

Comment: yeah try it, it will clean your gradle file internally for android

Comment: if you get trouble using that command, first enter into your app through cmd and use `gradlew clean` into

Comment: same thing again :(

Comment: have you run your cmd through administrator access??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156832/discussion-between-levon-petrosyan-and-stuti-kasliwal).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following step once, it may help you:

**step 1:** open cmd through administrator

**step 2:** navigate to your application by `cd <path to your project>`

**step 3:** run this command:  `./gradlew clean`

**step 4:** react-native run-android

Comment: `./gradlew clean`

Comment: it say there is no such command

Comment: you have to go to android folder in the root of your project

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed JDK and Android SDK properly? Are the `JAVA_HOME` and `ANDROID_HOME` properly placed in your environment variables?

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: I assume You are on Windows, then look for it like this: "Open the System pane under System and Security in the Control Panel, then click on Change settings.... Open the Advanced tab and click on Environment Variables" if you see ANDROID_HOME and it's pointing to your android SDK location it's ok. Same applies to JAVA_HOME

Comment: there is only ANDROID_HOME

Comment: Could you please try write `java -version` and `javac -version` to commandline? What's the result?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_141","javac" not recognized

Comment: Nice. You should install JDK. From the official [JDK download site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) you need to download and install the necessary binary ( Java SE Development Kit 8u148 - Windows x64 if you are using a 64 bit windows ). Then reboot and try these commands again.

Comment: If the installer doesn't add `JAVA_HOME` environment variable, you need to add it manually in System > Advanced System Settings > Advanced tab > Environment Variables.
Name: `JAVA_HOME`
Value: `<Your JDK directory> (Usually C:\Program Files\Java\jdk<version>)`

Comment: This verification helped me, I realized that in my case, the JAVA_HOME variable was missing, so this must be the first verification before attempting other solutions

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue while working on react-native project on Linux.
In my case issue occured because I linked some external plugin and then removed it without unlink. In that case you can attentively read your console error message. It should point to place that source an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with react native, just make sure you set up environment variables correctly for java compiler.
after this goto package.json file in your project:

change this:

"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-31.0.0.tar.gz",

to:
"react-native": "0.57.5",

save and run npm install

Source: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21722

Answer (score 0):

The solution if ur version of react-native >= 0.61.0. It shows error as when we add any plugin and use link command then it makes changes in android and ios folder. But when we remove plugin, it gets removed from package.json but inside android changes are not reverted and it gives error. So use below command to generate android folder again.
I hope it will solve the error-

```
sudo rm -rf android/ ios/

yarn add react-native-eject

npx react-native eject
```