# npm run android hangs on 'Loading dependency graph, done' (BlueWallet)

Tags: android, react-native, android-virtual-device

I'm trying to clone BlueWallet from [this github source](https://github.com/BlueWallet/BlueWallet).

I clone the project and installed the required packages. Also, the emulator is running with android studio AVD.

But whenever I try to run `npm start android` it hangs on text `Loading dependency graph, done.` and nothing more will happen!

it's weird because whenever I try to run the same scenario and commands to start a pure react-native connected to emulator it works with no problem.

the result for `npm start android` is as follow:

```
$ npm start android

> BlueWallet@3.8.3 start /home/Learning/ReactNative/BlueWallet
> node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start "android"

   ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────        ─┐
│                                                                                  │
│  Running Metro Bundler on port 8081.                                             │
│                                                                                  │
│  Keep Metro running while developing on any JS projects. Feel free to            │
│  close this tab and run your own Metro instance if you prefer.                   │
│                                                                                  │
│  https://github.com/facebook/react-native                                        │
│                                                                                  │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────    ─┘

Looking for JS files in
   /home/Learning/ReactNative/BlueWallet 

Loading dependency graph, done.
```

Comment: Using react-native start when app already installed on device. Using react-native run-android when we need to install app on device and start the server. But when we installed new package to our project, we need to restart server using react-native run-android

Comment: my problem is that it gets stuck at `Loading dependency graph, done.`. But when I start a pure react-native app with android with the emulator, will work with no problem.

Comment: Close the app and re-open it in your device, while the packager is still running.

Comment: close what app? I'm trying to create live develope mode so that my changes be displayed on the emulator. By default It creates a connection between founded emulator, But don't know why for this project it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Actually `Loading dependency graph, done` is not actually a bug and the server doesn't hang on anything. It's just waiting for the emulator to connect to it.

Here is what I did:

- In a separate terminal, I did run `npm start`, this way the server (packager) is starting.
- In another terminal, I run `npm run android`. Now the emulator will be selected and will connect on the port of 8081 which the server from the first command is running and everything will be fine.

**Note**: I did make some twists on some parts of the project and did something on OS as follow. If anyone in the future wanted to do the same, maybe be useful for him:

- set java home variable to be correct (add it to `bashrc` or `profile` or ..)

  ```
  export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-10-openjdk"
  export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
  ```
- set android SDK and other env variables;

  ```
  export ANDROID_HOME=/home/execut3/android-sdk
  export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/home/execut3/android-sdk
  export JAVA_OPTS='-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions --add-modules java.se.ee'
  export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/emulator:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
  ```
- to run emulator

  ```
  $ emulator -list-avds
  $ emulator -avd <avd name>
  ```
- If error `Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' react native` happened, in `android/app/src/main/java/com/bluewallet/MainApplication.java` in line 19, change it to `return true` to ignore debug. Also, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46770359/execution-failed-for-task-appcompiledebugjavawithjavac-react-native?rq=1) could be useful too.
- add `google()` repository in higher place than other in `android/build.gradle` file.
- change version of `react-native` to `0.57.5` in `package.json` file and remove `node_modules` then install again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I try whit "react-native run-android" when the aplication runs an error about "BASE_MAP.fill(255)" appears. Then I run "npm run prepare" that solve the error montioned above. I hope that my solution can to help you.

[The app runs in my Android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZoax.png)

Answer (score -1):

I face this problem sometimes ,specially when you kill node sever by pressing ctrl+c 
id did some things like unistalling node and install a lower version and the n install the latest version
running node server on another port

```
react-native start --port=8082
```

Comment: Sorry but it's not the right solution, Because it's already running on port 8081 fine. As I said It's running, I only need to run it also on Android so that android emulator could connect to it.