# How to find the app folder path in React-nativeProject

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

How can I view my compliated Android app folder in React-native? I'd like to view gradle config, but I can't find information anywhere how to get there.

Comment: You just have to find your **Project** folder. Then voila!

Comment: @HeisenBrg But how? I can't find it in react-native docs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native iOS and Android folders not present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270504/react-native-ios-and-android-folders-not-present)

Comment: How are you currently building your project if you don't know the path?

Comment: in which **folder** you used this command `react-native init project` ?

Comment: I used create-react-native-app to generate this app(it was suggested in [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)). When i use react-native init i have gradle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are referencing the React Native documentation, it is likely that you created your application using the `create-react-native-app` CLI. If this is the case, you will need to eject your application in order to modify native code (`npm run eject`). [Reference this page](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#caveats).

Alternatively, you can create a project using `react-native init`.