# exporting an apk of a front end developed via react-native and back end that's made up of Fire base and Node.js?

Tags: android, node.js, firebase, react-native, apk

As the title indicates I got an app recently with the client wanting me to test the code and the performance of the app. After doing that, I was asked to get the APK and publish it for a bonus but I'm not sure how I should go about this.

If more information is needed then please do note that.

I tried to google my way out of this but no luck since I couldn't find anyone who was in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see an ios tag in your question, so I assume you only want to build the Android apk, simply follow the official tutorial from Facebook [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android)

The generated apk will probably be output to `android/app/build/outputs/apk/app-release.apk`

Comment: Yes, that is true. So I assume it is no different from a regular react-native app build? and If I may I might ask a couple more questions in the next couple of days.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean a regular build, when you debug your app you are using `react-native run-android`, but now you are generating a release build that doesnt depend on your computer's js bundle.

Comment: See, I was only given two folders frontend and back end I wasn't given the android folder so I can't set the Gradle variables. This led me to assume that this is somewhat different from other react-native apps somehow.

Comment: Then I guess your project is based on Expo, you might want to look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44270504/react-native-ios-and-android-folders-not-present and that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42506068/how-can-i-regenerate-ios-folder-in-react-native-project

Comment: and if you don't want to eject from expo you might take a look at the official document here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/building-standalone-apps/